# The router does not work in the angular6 location

Tags: angular, location, router

The router does not work in the angular6 location.
My code is as follows. Suspected would be worth a place?

```
handleBackButtonPress() {
    this.subscription = this.location.subscribe(redirect => {
      if (redirect.pop === true) {
        alert('this is a backbutton click');
        this.router.navigate(['/users/me/watches']);
      }
    });
  }
```

I manage my router in each folder, and the code below defines the router I want to move.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { Resolver } from './resolver.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: '../home/home.module#HomeModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  exports: [RouterModule],
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  providers: [Resolver]
})
export class RoutingModule {}
```

Comment: what is the error

Comment: @Sajeetharan It's received well the alert, and then the router is not working properly functioning properly. There is a problem not to go to the URL.

Comment: where did you define the route? can you share your routing code

Comment: @SehaxX I updated the above question with respect to the router. Thank you.

Comment: But I'm wondering if we don't have to declare on the routing side. It(this.router.navigate) moves well to an undeclared path.